# Android form validation UI library

Tags: android, user-interface, validation

There is iOS [US2FormValidator](https://github.com/ustwo/US2FormValidator) library for user input validation (see the picture below). I think that library is better than the default of just popping an alert when something doesn't validate.

[image: US2FormValidator Preview]

I'm looking for how to do such things on Android. Are there some Android analogs of [US2FormValidator](https://github.com/ustwo/US2FormValidator)?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The pop-up effect you have shown on your screenshot can be achieved using Android's built-in `setError(String)` method on `EditText` widgets.

Also, you can leverage the power of annotations using the [Android Saripaar](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar) library that I've authored.

first add the library:

```
compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.2'
```

The library is very simple to use. In your activity annotate the `View` references you would like to validate as in the following example.

```
@Order(1)
private EditText fieldEditText;

@Order(2)
@Checked(message = "You must agree to the terms.")
private CheckBox iAgreeCheckBox;

@Order(3)
@Length(min = 3, message = "Enter atleast 3 characters.")
@Pattern(regex = "[A-Za-z]+", message = "Should contain only alphabets")
private TextView regexTextView;

@Order(4)
@Password(min = 6, scheme = Password.Scheme.ALPHA_NUMERIC_MIXED_CASE_SYMBOLS)
private EditText passwordEditText;

@Order(5)
@ConfirmPassword
private EditText confirmPasswordEditText;
```

The `order` attribute specifies the order in which the fields have to be validated.

In your `onCreate()` method instantiate a new `Validator` object. and call `validator.validate()` inside any of your event listeners.

You'll receive callbacks on `onSuccess` and `onFailure` methods of the `ValidationListener`.

If you want to show a pop-up as show in the image above then do the following,

```
public void onValidationFailed(View failedView, Rule<?> failedRule) {
    if (failedView instanceof Checkable) {
        Toast.makeText(this, failedRule.getFailureMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (failedView instanceof TextView) {
        TextView view = (TextView) failedView;
        view.requestFocus();
        view.setError(failedRule.getFailureMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Android Saripaar is definitely the way to go! :D

Comment: What about Mobile number validation?

Comment: @RegEx Annotation - Use regular expressions, there is no standard format for phone numbers.

Comment: Okay, Thanks! I did not find Number rule for greater than 0

Comment: `@NumberRule(gt = 0, message = "Number should be greater than zero.")`

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say greater than -1

Comment: Do you mean, for instance -2 is greater than -1?

Comment: -2 is not greater than -1, it's less than -1. So, you should use `@NumberRule(lt = -1, message = "Number should be less than -1.")`

Comment: No I mean I should not allow user negative values

Comment: No, I tried that but it was showing error, Because my number type was Decimal and I want to Invalidate Negative decimal. Any work around?

Comment: The attributes accept double, so that you can use integers as well as floating point values. What error are you getting?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45768/discussion-between-akshay-taru-and-ragunath-jawahar)

Comment: @RagunathJawahar how to get message from Strings.xml as my app support multiple languages.

Comment: @AZ_ use the messageResId attribute instead of the message attribute in your annotation.

Comment: There is no `@Required` annotation in 2.0.3? I had to use `@NotEmpty` instead.

Comment: @Sithu, yes you are right. This answer was written during the v1 days.

Answer (score 28):

Android has extremely easy-to-use built-in validation mechanism which is great enough. See the following link:
http://blog.donnfelker.com/2011/11/23/android-validation-with-edittext/

Comment: Link broken, this is up (2015/07/14): 
http://www.donnfelker.com/android-validation-with-edittext/

Answer (score 4):

I've just come across ValidationKomensky that you may find useful

https://github.com/inmite/android-validation-komensky

[image]