# Android : Form Validation Library

Tags: android, android-layout, validation

I am trying to find a form validation library in android. Is there such a thing ?

I have a registration form that I want to validate its fields. If the user enters an invalid data, I want to put a red warning mark at the right of the field and pop up a tooltip that he entered an invalid data.

I know about the `android:inputType` but this is not what I want

Comment: `Is there such a thing ?` nothing...do it manually checking string length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about any such libraries. But if you are working with EditTexts, then your best option is to use a custom [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html):

```
class TextCheck implements TextWatcher
{
    private EditText editor;

    public TextCheck(EditText editor)
    {
        this.editor = editor;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
    {
        // check the text, and if the user entered 
        // something wrong, change your edittext
        if(something wrong)
        {
            editor.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); //for example
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0){}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3){}


}
```

And then you can use it on all your EditTexts like

```
EditText editor = (EditText) findViewById(...your id...);
editor.addTextChangedListener(new TextCheck(editor));
```

Comment: Thank you very much ... it helped me alot with my validations.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there such a thing?

Ah.. yes there is one and you can find it [here](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar).

It does form validation for you, using but not limited to **Annotations**. To find out what the library does please visit the following [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12335430/421372) where I have described the usage of the library.

If you want to write new rules you can always extend the [Rule](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/blob/master/src/com/mobsandgeeks/saripaar/Rule.java) class.

PS: I am the author of the library.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but you can try this excellent [Android Validation library](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar) and visit this [Stackoverflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776829/android-form-validation-ui-library) and this [Stackoverflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613321/form-validation-library-for-android) for usage examples because I found the main librarys how-tos kinda of hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar. You can improve this code and adapt for your necessity.

**EditTextWithValidation.java**

```
public class EditTextWithValidation extends EditText implements OnTouchListener {
    private EditTextValidator mValidator;

    public EditTextWithValidation(Context context) {
        super(context);

        initialize();
    }

    public EditTextWithValidation(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        initialize();
    }

    public EditTextWithValidation(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        initialize();
    }

    public EditTextValidator getCustomValidator() {
        return mValidator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        setError(null);

        return false;
    }

    private void initialize() {
        mValidator = new EditTextValidator(this);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
}
```

**EditTextValidator.java**

```
public class EditTextValidator {
    private static final String TAG = EditTextValidator.class.getName();

    private enum ValidationResult {
        Ok, Rules, Mismatch
    }

    private EditText mParent;
    private Pattern mValidationPattern;
    private int mValidationErrorMsgId;
    private boolean mAllowEmpty;
    private EditText mMatchView;
    private int mMismatchMsgId;
    private int mMinLength;
    private int mMaxLength;
    private ValidationResult mValidationResult;

    public EditTextValidator(EditText parent) {
        this.mParent = parent;
    }

    public void setAllowEmpty(boolean allowEmpty) {
        this.mAllowEmpty = allowEmpty;
    }

    public void setValidationErrorMsgId(int validationErrorMsgId) {
        this.mValidationErrorMsgId = validationErrorMsgId;
    }

    public void setValidationRules(String strPattern, int validationErrorMsgId, boolean allowEmpty) {
        try {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(strPattern)) {
                mValidationPattern = Pattern.compile(strPattern);
            }
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            ToastUtil.toastShort("Invalid validation pattern!");
        }

        this.mValidationErrorMsgId = validationErrorMsgId;
        this.mAllowEmpty = allowEmpty;
    }

    public void setValidLength(int min, int max) {
        mMinLength = min;
        mMaxLength = max;
    }

    public void shouldMatch(EditText matchView, int mismatchMsgId) {
        this.mMatchView = matchView;
        this.mMismatchMsgId = mismatchMsgId;
    }

    public boolean validate() {
        mValidationResult = ValidationResult.Ok;

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mParent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mParent.getWindowToken(), 0);

        final String text = mParent.getText().toString();
        final int length = text.length();

        if (mValidationResult == ValidationResult.Ok && !mAllowEmpty && 0 == text.length()) {
            mValidationResult = ValidationResult.Rules;
        }

        if (mValidationResult == ValidationResult.Ok) {
            if (mMinLength != 0 && length < mMinLength) {
                mValidationResult = ValidationResult.Rules;
            } else if (mMaxLength != 0 && length > mMaxLength) {
                mValidationResult = ValidationResult.Rules;
            }
        }

        if (mValidationResult == ValidationResult.Ok && mValidationPattern != null) {
            Matcher m = mValidationPattern.matcher(text);
            if (!m.matches())
                mValidationResult = ValidationResult.Rules;
        }

        if (mValidationResult == ValidationResult.Ok && mMatchView != null) {
            if (mMatchView.getText().toString().compareTo(text) != 0)
                mValidationResult = ValidationResult.Mismatch;
        }

        if (ValidationResult.Ok == mValidationResult) {
            mParent.setError(null);
        } else {
            CharSequence error = null;
            if (ValidationResult.Rules == mValidationResult)
                error = MyApplication.getContext().getText(mValidationErrorMsgId);
            else if (ValidationResult.Mismatch == mValidationResult)
                error = MyApplication.getContext().getText(mMismatchMsgId);

            mParent.setError(error);
            mParent.requestFocus();
        }

        return mValidationResult == ValidationResult.Ok;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
mSignupEmail = (EditTextWithValidation) root.findViewById(R.id.signup_email);
mSignupEmail.getCustomValidator().setValidationRules(
        "[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*\\.(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})",
        R.string.email_answer_validation_msg,
        false);
mSignupEmail.getCustomValidator().setValidLength(0, 50);

…

mSignupPassword = (EditTextWithValidation) root.findViewById(R.id.signup_password);
mSignupPassword.getCustomValidator().setValidationRules(
                    "[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()]{6,20}",
        R.string.password_validation_msg,
        false);

…

mSignupConfirmPassword = (EditTextWithValidation) root.findViewById(R.id.signup_confirm_password);
mSignupConfirmPassword.getCustomValidator().setAllowEmpty(true);
mSignupConfirmPassword.getCustomValidator().shouldMatch(mSignupPassword, R.string.password_mismatch);
mSignupConfirmPassword.getCustomValidator().setValidationErrorMsgId(R.string.password_validation_msg);

…

if (mSignupEmail.getCustomValidator().validate() && mSignupPassword.getCustomValidator().validate() && mSignupConfirmPassword.getCustomValidator().validate()) {
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos

Go to: `Utils` -> `Android-Validator` -> `View Demo`

There are a bunch of other cool libraries in this app as well. The good thing is that you can view demo of each library and get the link to github repo of that particular library if you like it. It's very useful.